# Rails Geocoder only when lat/long not present

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails for app with geocoder.

I'm important ical files so sometimes they have a lat/long already in the files, sometimes they don't.

How do I tell the model to geocode only if lat/long are not already present? And how do i tell geocoder to use those lat/long and trust them?

```
geocoded_by :full_address
after_validation :geocode, :if => :address1_changed?
```

Will geocoder just understand that I have the long/lat if i just set latitude and longitude directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a custom conditional.

```
after_validation :geocode, if: :address_changed_and_lat_long_blank?


private 

def address_changed_and_lat_long_blank?
  address1_changed? || lat.blank? || long.blank?
end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can I use `:location_changed?  unless self.geo` since I only want to do it if geo is not already present?

Comment: yep. I'd use `if: :location_changed?, unless: :already_geocoded?` and then have a method called `already_geocoded?` that returns `self.geo`

There are some docs on it [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#using-if-and-unless-with-a-symbol) under **8.4 Multiple Conditions for Callbacks**